# My openpose builds don't have a necessary .bin file. Building with CMake according to installation.md

Tags: windows, parameters, cmake, output, openpose

I need to run openpose and get the output keypoint data from it.  I believe the description on how to do that exists here:

https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/blob/master/doc/demo_overview.md

But, after following the instructions for building openpose as described here:

https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/blob/master/doc/installation.md

The necessary file called "openpose.bin" does not exist in the CMake build, or anywhere else on my computer.

I think the problem might be related to the use of the JSON file described here:

https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/blob/master/doc/output.md

But I am not sure.  It doesn't seem like that method for output saving, and the method I am referencing in the first link depend on each other.

Cloning the GitHub creates a couple of files: openpose/include/openpose/headers.hpp and openpose/include/openpose/flags.hpp

The comments in flags.hpp say that they do not automatically get included with headers, and I think this may be related to my problem, as some of the files related to saving output are referenced in flags.hpp, and I do not know enough about programming to know exactly how to include flags.hpp

```
#ifndef OPENPOSE_FLAGS_HPP
#define OPENPOSE_FLAGS_HPP

// Note: This class is not included within the basic OpenPose `headers.hpp` and must be explicitly included. In
// addition, Google Flags library must also be linked to the resulting binary or library. OpenPose library does
// not force to use Google Flags, but the OpenPose examples do so.

…

DEFINE_string(write_json,               "",             "Directory to write OpenPose output in JSON format. It includes body, hand, and face pose"
                                                        " keypoints (2-D and 3-D), as well as pose candidates (if `--part_candidates` enabled).");
```

I am able to make a demo run that renders an image with visual keypoints superimposed, but what I need is the parameters for those keypoints to perform further processing.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. you don't have the `openpose.bin` file, then how can you run the demo that renders images? Does either of the two `cmake` calls return an error?